# Previous table of simplex algorithm

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have this problem of simplex method which shows cycle .

Problem : Maximize $Z=10x_1-57x_2-9x_3-24x_4$
Constraint to : 
           $ 0.5x_1-5.5x_2-2.5x_3+9x_4<=0 $,
           $ 0.5x_1-1.5x_2-0.5x_3+x_4<=0 $,$ x_1<=1 $

I know that next table of this problem can be found by gaussian method . But how can I found previous table ?

So far I have received a comment from an user . What is meant here by previous table ? To clarify this statement, Look at the following :

Maximize $p = (1/2)x + 3y + z + 4w$ subject to
$x + y + z + w <= 40$
,$2x + y - z - w >= 10$,
$w - y >= 10$

Here in the image I have given two iterations in tabular format . Table 1 is the previous table of table 2 . So hope the language clarification is okay .

[image]

Comment: Can you double check the problem statement? As written now, there is no solution because $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$ and $x_4 \rightarrow -\infty$ meets your constraints and makes $Z \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Can you give a sample example of any lp problem for which previous table can be calculated ?

Comment: Since I'm not familiar with the language of previous table, I don't think I can.

Comment: hope so now you can understand the language of problem .

Comment: Did you generate this added example by hand? If so, why did you pick $x$ to enter the basis? The standard approach would have called for $w$ to enter the basis, since it has the most negative entry in the objective row.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That is the process I know but I guess I never learned to call them tableaus. As Michael C. Grant says in his answer, there is no way to reverse it from the tableau only.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe this is possible due to the information loss that necessarily takes place at each step of the simplex algorithm.

Recall that the purpose of a step of the simplex algorithm is to improve the current solution by selecting a variable to enter to the basis (in other words $\gt 0$), increasing its value to the point where one of the existing variables has to leave the basis (i.e, $=0$). For instance, in the example you've added, $x$ has entered and $s_2$ has exited the basis. Each new tableau represents a different, but *equivalent* expression of the optimization problem. Gauss-Jordan elimination operations are used to perform this pivoting process.

There are several ways that this process irreversibly eliminates information:

- The entering variable/pivoting column is typically selected based on which element in the bottom row has the smallest (i.e., most negative) value. (I notice you did not use this criterion in your example, for some reason.) Once the pivot is complete, this value will be zero---as are the values corresponding to the other basic variables. There is no way tell which of the basic variables is "newest" simply by looking at the bottom row.
- Once a pivot row is selected---typically the row with the smallest ratio between the right-hand column and the pivot column---the row is normalized so that the pivot value is 1. For instance, in your example, the second row was divided by 2. There is no way to tell after the what this scaling was, so you cannot recover the original values of the pivot row.
- The normalized pivot row is subtracted from each of the other rows to zero out the other elements of the pivot column. For instance, in your example, the scales for rows 1, 3, and 4 are -1, 0, and +0.5, respectively. Once the subtraction is complete, there is no way to know what those scales were. So you cannot recover the original values of the non-pivot rows.

Hopefully it's clear, then, that the simplex algorithm is not a reversible process. Information is lost at every step in the progress towards a solution. You can't even determine what the *original* model was simply by looking at an intermediate tableau.

Comment: For this particular problem I want to have a no-degenerate vertex . After that degenerate vertex , A degenerate vertex will come .

Comment: I'm afraid I do not know what you're trying to say here.

Comment: Degeneracy is of course a well known problem, and there are a variety of ways to handle it. Trying to return to the previous tableau doesn't seem wise, but if you decide you must, you will simply have to save the necessary information to recover the previous tableau: the pivot row and column, and the scaling factors used in the G-J elimination.

Comment: I want to have a problem of lp in where the starting point will be degenerate and after 1 iteration , I will have a degenerate vertex . Also that problem must be a problem of simplex which will show cycle . Can you help me in this regard ?

Comment: Methods for avoiding cycles are well known; see, for instance, [Bland's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bland's_rule), the  or the lexicographic method, or the [Criss-cross algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criss-cross_algorithm).

Comment: I do not want to avoid cycle in lp problem . Rather I want to have a lp problem which show cycling .

Comment: The lp problem must start from non-degenerate vertex . Can you give me one such example ? Then I will accept this answer .

Comment: Google is your friend here, but [here](http://people.orie.cornell.edu/miketodd/or630/SimplexCyclingExample.pdf) is just one such example.

Comment: This problem start from non-degenerate vertex .The example you give starts from degenerate vertex .

Comment: So construct a model using the first tableau that gives a degenerate vertex.

Comment: Look, I am frankly mystified why you are so insistent on me doing the work here. My time is more valuable than a bounty. You clearly understand the problem pretty well, and there are *tons* of discussions of degenerate vertices on the web.

Comment: Actually I have tried a lot and can not find any problem on cycling starting with degenerate vertex . It will be very helpful for me if u can give me such problem .This is my thesis topics . So I really want your help .

Comment: I am really want your help . I will remember your help .

Comment: As I said above: go to the example I gave you, and *construct a model from the first tableau that gives a degenerate vertex.* Every tableau corresponds to a set of inequalities, not just the first. That will give you exactly what you need. I cannot help further.